# Como o PHP trata expressão temporárias quanto à memória?

Tags: php, memória, expressões

No PHP, é possível fazer iteração dos elementos de um `array` através do `foreach`, tanto com a variável que o contém como com o que o PHP chamou de "*temporary array expression*".
Exemplo:

```
$myArray = ['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b'];
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}


foreach(['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b'] as $key => $value){
    echo $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Também é possível fazer referência de cada elemento de um `array`, e é aí que entra a minha questão.

O código abaixo funciona corretamente:

```
$myArray = ['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b'];
foreach ($myArray as $key => &$value) {
   $value = sprintf('"%s!"', $value);
}
print_r($myArray); //imprime: Array ( [a] => "a!" [b] => "b!" )
```

Já esse código vai gerar um erro fatal (o que eu já esperava):

```
foreach (['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b'] as $key => &$value) {
   $value = sprintf('"%s!"', $value);
}
//Erro:  Cannot create references to elements of a temporary array expression
```

Eu já sei que tentar passar uma declaração por referência gera erro, mas o meu foco não é esse, e sim que o erro diz em um trecho "... *temporary array expression*...".

Referente a esse trecho, tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Qual é a forma com o que o PHP trata, em cada um dos casos, quanto ao uso da memória, valores atribuídos à variáveis e valores declarados diretamente em *loops*, retornos de funções ou em passagem de parâmetros?

Por exemplo, como seria tratado o `array` passado por parâmetro nesse exemplo?

```
  call_user_func_array('print_r', [$_POST, false]);
```

- O coletor de lixo entra em cena em casos como o citado acima ou o PHP já descarta automaticamente logo após a linha em que é utilizado a "expressão temporária"?

Comment: Pergunta relacionada em inglês (porém não responde à sua dúvida): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772958/is-there-a-rational-explanation-for-this-php-call-by-value-behavior-or-php-bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O PHP, como nosso amigo @heat falou, se considera Orientado a Objetos, ou seja, ele criará uma instância lógica na primeira vez que ele ver a variável.

Caso essa variável seja chamada como `echo`, `print`, `print_f`, `printr`, o PHP vai apresentar erro, porque não há nenhum dado alocado nela...

Quanto a lixeira, ele cuidará disso sozinho. Não precisamos instanciar a lixeira como fazemos no java ou, em alguns casos, na linguagem C++. O PHP vai tratar disso no Side-Server, e nada podemos fazer quanto a isso.

Posso dar algumas dicas para você caso queria reutilizar uma variável ou caso tenha problema no SQL. Sempre, digo SEMPRE MESMO, feche a conexão MySQL/mysqli para que possa usar seguramente em outro momento; e, caso queira, declare como nula a variável antes de usar, isso vai limpar a alocação dela e vai deixar livre para novas entradas.

Na sua dúvida do *loop*, acho que já é bastante claro, né? O PHP vai criar alocações temporárias enquanto lê o *loop*, após disso, se você não declarar novo `array`, ela será liberada para nova consulta.

Na sua dúvida `call_user_func_array`, apesar de nunca ter precisado usar, me parece que dará erro fatal, veja que `print_r` não gera array, mas sim o imprime, ok?

Comment: Não, o call_user_func_array funciona corretamente no exemplo. inclusive ele imprime `Array()` nesse caso apresentado, pois ele aceita dois parâmetros `print_r(mixed $data, boolean $return)`

Comment: O exemplo do `call_user_func_array` chamando o `print_r` foi pra representar o uso de uma "expressão temporária de array". O `print_r` imprime o valor do `array`, e o `call_user_func_array` chama uma função usando um array como se fosse o parâmetro da mesma. O que eu quero saber é como o PHP trataria o [$_POST, false], que não foi atribuído a nenhuma variável

Comment: Oops, minha culpa, desculpe. Pela documentação dele [http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php] o `call_user_func_array` passará primeiro a instrução de `echo` e depois a do array... nesse caso teríamos de saber se o `$_POST` vai ser um array. Abraços

Comment: Então, como disse agora pouco, de fato não dará erro na hipótese do $_POST ser um array.. Senão você vai cair naquele errinho de passar uma string/int/boolean (qualquer coisa que não seja o array) quando era esperado um array...

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o manual é [php for](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.for.php):

```
for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
statement
```

Ele avalia a primeira expressão apenas uma vez, tanto faz se é um $i ou uma array expression [], a cada iteração ele verifica o boleano da expr2 e no fim da iteração executa a expr3.

Como ele está dentro de um bloco, é criado um contexto para a execução dos comandos dentro do for

Uma vez terminada o bloco de execução as variaveis já podem ser marcadas para serem liberadas.

Outra curiosidade é o php se considerar orientado a expressão [php expression](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.expressions.php)